# tab pane not working when inserted inside a dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

i'm trying to insert my working tabs inside a dropdown, but unfortunately the tabs is not working . I don't have any idea why i doesn't work anymore.

here's a piece of my code

```html
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
  <li data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#">Vehicles</a>


    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <hr/>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-header material-tab" role="tablist">


        <li class="active"><a href="#cars" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="#images" role="vans" data-toggle="tab">Vans</a></li>

        <li><a href="#suv" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SUVs & Pickup</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content white-bg-tabs">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="cars" role="tabpanel">
          Cars Content
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="vans" role="tabpanel">
          Vans Content
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="suv" role="tabpanel">
          SUVs & Pickup Content
        </div>
      </div>

    </ul>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Owners</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Promotions</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
</ul>
```

i don't know if it's the doing of my css code. i'm using bootstrap and some plugins like slicknav.

Comment: Can you provide the full HTML/CSS/JS or JSFiddle for your issue?

Comment: @PhaniKumarM i don't know how to add bootstrap and other external sources it seems buggy. hmmm but i can provide the HTML/CSS/JS on JSFiddle jsfiddle.net/jre5n9dh/

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/55dda here's the tabs that i'm trying to insert.

Comment: may not be the cause of the issue - but the id on the second tab pane ("#vans") does not match the href on the second 'a' ("#images")

Comment: @gavgrif fixed it. same result :)